# Como pegar data object em php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou passando um objeto do angular para o php, mas o php insisti e "dizer" que os dados que estão vindo não é um object, o que devo fazer? Como posso pegar essas dados no php?

Segue os meus códigos

angular:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('logradouroCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
var pegaMsgsLogra = function () {
    idCep = $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep');
    idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var dados = {
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep')
    }
    console.log(dados);
    $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/vcApp/www/php/pegaMsgsLogra.php", dados).success(function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}

pegaMsgsLogra();
```

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);
print_r($data);
$idUsuario = $data->idUsuario;
$idCep = $data->idCep;

echo 'id usuario '.$idUsuario.' id cep '.$idCep;
?>
```

Coloquei o console.log(data) e print_r(data) para ver o que está indo para o php
Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Erros estão aqui:  `$data->idUsuario` e `$data->idCep`.

Comment: Como? Está errado fazer isso @felipsmartins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muda o `$http.get` para `$http.post`

O $http.get não te permite passa um conjunto de dados por parametro.

[$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

O $http.post te permite passa um conjunto de dados por parametro

[$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)